# Comparing string variables and ignoring outside whitespace

Tags: c#, .net, xml, string, if-statement

I have this function (part of a C# .Net DLL) which locates XML elements with a specific value and replaces the text. It uses recursion:

```
   private bool ReplaceNameInXMLDocument(XElement pElement, string strOldName, string strNewName)
    {
        bool bReplaced = false;

        try
        {
            if (pElement.HasElements)
            {
                foreach (var pSubElement in pElement.Descendants())
                {
                    ReplaceNameInXMLDocument(pSubElement, strOldName, strNewName);
                }
            }
            else if (pElement.Value == strOldName)
            {
                pElement.Value = strNewName;
            }

            bReplaced = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            SimpleLog.Log(ex);
        }

        return bReplaced;
    }
```

The only issue I have is related to whitespace. Imagine `strOldName` is `Happy` but in the XML data file the value there (for what ever reason) is `Happy`  (it has an extra space). At the moment my comparison method is not locating the match because of the difference with whitepsace.

I realise I could change the `else` clause like this:

```
{
    string strExistingValue = pElement.Value.Trim();
    if(strExistingValue = strOldName)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

But is there any other way that I can compare `strOldName` against the `string` element and automatically ignore outside whitespace? This is because I know that the variable `strOldName` has already been `Trim`med. Is there a simpler comparison beyond my suggested adjustment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no *BLC* string compare/equals that would *trim* for you. However, you could easily create an extension method

<sub>***Note** : This is just an example, you would need to make sure it does what you want*</sub>

```
public static class Extensions
{
     public static bool MyIsEqual(
            this string source, 
            string value, 
            StringComparison comparisonType = StringComparison.CurrentCulture)
       => string.Equals(source?.Trim(), value?.Trim(), comparisonType);
}
```

Usage

```
if(strOldName.MyIsEqual(pElement.Value))
   ...
```